# basic perl conditional script not working

Tags: perl

I am a beginner to perl and have just been messing around trying to create little scripts. I'm not sure what is wrong here but it just falls through to the `else` every time as if nothing I input satisfies the `if` or `elsif` conditions. Is it because `eq` is the wrong operator? Or is there something else wrong in my code? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "what is your name?\n";
my $name = readline STDIN; 
print "Hello $name How are you today?\n";

my $feeling = readline STDIN;

if ($feeling eq "happy") {
    print "that's good!\n";
}
elsif ($feeling eq "good") {
    print "okay!\n";
}
else {
    print "Interesting\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `chomp($feeling);`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "what is your name?\n";
my $name = readline STDIN;
chomp($name);
print "Hello $name How are you today?\n";

my $feeling = readline STDIN;

chomp($feeling);
if ($feeling eq "happy") {
 print "that's good!\n";
}
elsif ($feeling eq "good") {
 print "okay!\n";
}
else {
 print "Interesting\n";
}
```

readline STDIN captures every character typed along with last enter hit as `\n`, say if you type `"happy"` and hit enter for `$feeling` then its accepted as `"happy\n"` notice `\n` is because enter hit to remove last `\n` newline character use [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) removes any trailing string

Comment: You still need to chomp the user input when using the `<>` diamond operator.

Comment: @RonBergin corrected, thanks, curious to know whats different between `<>` and `readline STDIN`

Comment: @PramodShinde readline is the internal function that the `<>` operator uses, but can be used directly.  It's just more verbose.

Comment: is there any way to add another value to an if or elsif statement? like if i wanted it to print "that's good" for "happy" "happy!" "excited" etc? or would i have to just make more elsif statements?

Comment: `chomp removes any trailing string` that is incorrect.

Comment: @4n0n9m0u5, you can easily add other values to the given/when structure, which I showed in my answer; `when(['happy','excited']){...}`.

Answer (score 0):

[chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) is used to "chomp off" the input record separator, which by default is a newline character.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;                               # to use things like 'say' and 'given'

say "what is your name?";                # 'say' is like 'print', but means you don't have to use '\n'

my $name = <STDIN>;                      # good to include angled brackets <>
chomp($name);                            # remove the newline when entering the number

say qq{Hello $name, how are you today?}; # qq{} acts like double-quotes ("")

my $feeling = <STDIN>;
chomp $feeling;                          # notice parenthese aren't always needed
                                         # you could also do chomp(my $feeling=<STDIN>);

given (lc $feeling){                     # 'given' is Perl's version of a Switch and lc makes input lowercase
   when('happy') { say q{That's good.} } # q{} acts like single-quotes ('')
   when('good')  { say q{Okay!}        }
   default       { say q{Interesting}  } # your else-case
}
```

As the warnings suggest, `given` is experimental until smartmatch is figured out.  It is perfectly acceptable to use the if-elsif-else structure, if you choose.